# Files not loaded after deploying on heroku, Phaser 2

Tags: heroku, phaser-framework

Good night, I have a problem, because during the development of the game I had no problems in loading the files. But when I deployed to heroku the game did not load multiple files.

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

**Local:**

[image]

**Heroku:**

[image]

Comment: If you right click on your browser and hit "inspect" you should see a "console" printing errors. Those errors will be helpful in debugging the problem. 
It could be several things like those images weren't uploaded or it can't load from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would run the build locally and check the build/dist folder.

Are the images there?

Perhaps webpack/parcel does not bundle all the files as you want, due to misconfiguration.

As an example, in webpack you could have `CopyWebpackPlugin` defined in webpack.dev.js instead of wepack.common.js